# Integral solution needed

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help in solving the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{g}{f}}\int_{\frac{g}{f}}^{\frac{c}{jdef}+\frac{g}{f}}\int_{(j-1)u}^{\frac{c}{def}+\frac{jg}{f}-u}\frac{K!e^{-t-u-v}(1-e^{-v})^{K-j-1}\{t-(j-1)u\}^{j-2}}{(j-1)!(j-2)!(K-j-1)!}dtdudv$$

where $c, d, e, f$ are all constants and $K, j$ are integers with $K \geq j$. As a first step I can integrate with respect to $v$ to get following form $$\int_{\frac{g}{f}}^{\frac{c}{jdef}+\frac{g}{f}}\int_{(j-1)u}^{\frac{c}{def}+\frac{jg}{f}-u}\frac{K!(1-e^{-\frac{g}{f}})^{N-j}e^{-t-u}\{t-(j-1)u\}^{j-2}}{(j-1)!(j-2)!(K-j)!}dtdu$$

But after that I am unable to proceed.

Comment: can you tell the expanded from of CAS and WA? I did not get what they mean?

Comment: I think you mean wolfram alpha by WA. Yes i tried but was not able to get anything

Comment: Integrands $e^{-x^2}$ will yield special functions. I fear such show up here. Keeping track of all the constants and parameters is much work and error prone. I would try to warm up with some easy instances (choosing the constants and parameters such that the resulting integral is relatively simple). before tackling the general case.

Comment: I will appreciate if I get the answer for special case with $f=d=e=1$. Thank you.

Comment: @mvw can't we replace $t-(j-1)u$ with some variable $z$ and then try to solve it?

Comment: $t-(j-1)u$ contains two integration variables, I guess that will not work.

Comment: When you get down to it, this is just a constant times e^(-t-u)*(t - c*u)^n, where c and n are just some numbers. Expand (t - c*u)^n using the binomial theorem. This will expand the integrand into quite a few terms in the form of k*e^(-t-u)*t^p*u^q. Unfortunately, this is an integral similar to the one which defined the gamma function, which does not have a closed form solution for arbitrary bounds. So I highly doubt this one does, either. Out of curiosity, how did this integral arise?

Comment: @florence this is from a research paper. Can you help me in getting to the term $e^{-t-u}*(t-cu)^n$? After words I can expand it as you mention in your comment

Comment: The second integral is already is in that form (where c = j - 1, n = j-2), just times a constant (albeit a really complicated one). But my main point was, I doubt you can expand in any way to get a closed form solution.

Comment: @florence you are right. But, I think the first argument of the generalized incomplete gamma function will be a positive integer and we can use the series representation given here (third formula) http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma3/06/01/01/01/02/ and can proceed further. After solving the inner integral and using the above series, I feel that the integral can again be represented by the same series due to the positive integer powers of the variable $u$